# How BroadcastChannel API handles multiple/concurrent messages?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, cross-browser, broadcast-channel

Have a scenario, where 3 tabs are communicating via Broadcast channel API. But if one of the tab is taking some time to execute `onMessage` event (due to some delay) what will happen to new messages.

Example **:**

tab 1 : have a debug point in onMessage()

tab 2 : send -> message1, message2, message3

tab 3 : send -> message4, message5

But `tab1.onMessage` receives only first message i.e. message1. Other messages are discarded.